# Are SQL field types case sensitive

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering if field types are case sensitive in SQL, specifically in postgresql.
As far as I know SQL key words are generally case insensitive but does this also apply to types?
So if I have:

```
SELECT CAST(item1 AS INT)
```

is that the same as:

```
SELECT CAST(item1 AS int)
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, any named entities in SQL are case insensitive. So are reserved keywords.